# Adding 2 contacts (both populated with ?cid in the URL) to a webform is creating an error

Tags: webform-civicrm

Im using CiviCRM 5.13.1 and Webform CiviCRM 7.x-4.26.

Im adding 2 individual contacts to the form. I want them both to be populated by cids.

But when I add them, contact one is fine. I can set to static and populate by CID1.

But contact 2 is automatically set to autocomplete. I cannot change it. Even when I save it without change I get a

> An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site
>   administrator.

When I look at the Drupal log I see

> Illegal choice in Specify Relationship(s) element.

Anyone help??

Comment: Apols all. I did a lot of messing around with relationships which broke a few things. Clearing the CiviCRM cache worked for me.

Comment: No problem - can you perhaps add some screenshot - example of what you have working so that others can see how you did this?